# Find distribution that minimises a function of its moments

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Imagine a probability density function $f(x)$, and let's note its $n$th non-centred moment $x_{n}$.

The mean $x_{1}$ is fixed.

How can I find $f(x)$ so that it minimises some given function of the moments? In my case $x_{3}-x_{1}x_{2}$.

This is like minimising a functional, but as the functional in question doesn't depend on the derivatives, I don't know how to do.

Many thanks!

Comment: In general it seems that $x_3-x_1x_2$ can be arbitrarily negative, since $x_2\ge0$ always and $x_1=x_3=0$ when $f$ is an even function.

Comment: That's true, well pointed... Do you know of a general method that could be used for other functions of the moments?